# Blazor WASM local development cannot fetch remote data

Tags: .net-5, blazor-webassembly

I am using Blazor WASM .NET 5.0.4 and a local ASP.NET 5 Server.
I set the local ASP.NET server to local IP (in this case `192.168.188.31`) with a specific port, in my case `44302`.
On Blazor WASM I set the base address to said IP in `Program.cs`.

Now when I start up the Blazor WASM on my local PC I can fetch the sample weather data from the ASP.NET server just fine.
However if I visit the Blazor WASM site from an external device, such like my mobile phone, I can view all the pages like I would on PC, but as soon as I try to fetch the sample weather data, I just get a `Loading...` message and after some time I get a time out error: `net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` with stacktrace

```
blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: TypeError: Failed to fetch
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: TypeError: Failed to fetch
   at System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions.<GetFromJsonAsyncCore>d__9`1[[Client.Pages.FetchData.WeatherForecast[], Client, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext()
   at Client.Pages.FetchData.OnInitializedAsync() in D:\Dev\C#\meine Projekte\ProjectNextGen\ClientSide\Client\Pages\FetchData.razor:line 43
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle)
```

First I though that I made some technical errors, but this behavior can be seen with a fresh Blazor WASM project as well.

[image]

[image]

What do I have to do in order to fetch data from an external device such as my phone correctly?

Comment: What happens when you type `https://192.168.188.31:44302/WeatherForecast` in your phone's browser address bar?

Comment: @GSerg That was actually quite helpful. I could not connect to it by phone. After allowing the ports on my firewall, I could connect. The next thing is now that I have trouble with my self signed certificate when fetching the data with my phone, but with the non-SSL URI I can now fetch the data.
Thank you very much!